# Custom VPN logic for iOS

Tags: ios, proxy, vpn

I want to know if I can add a custom handler as VPN in iOS. In other word, let say that I have a custom code which encrypt TCP-IP requests and at other end decrypt them. But the process is highly customized and it is not like any other known VPN protocols. So I need to have my custom logic in place.

In Windows I used TAP-ADAPTER from OpenVPN and SOCKS2TAP from BADVPN projects to do so. I also provided a HTTP/HTTPS/Socks proxy protocol for users to use. But I was searching for a way to port my app to iOS and cant think of any way to do so.

I either need to find a way to  add my custom code to the iOS's VPN mechanism like what Cisco did or I need to find a way to keep my application open and then somehow act as simple local HTTP/HTTPS proxy.

Unfortunately AFAIK I cant do any of them. I cant keep my application open for long time and I dont have access to VPN API as apple is very secretive about them.

So do any of you people, have any idea or experience about this issue?

Regards,

Comment: Your only option is to build your encryption in your app on top of a socket interface such as CFSocket https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html but you cannot offer this as a network "service" to other apps running on iOS

Comment: @Paulw11 But how some apps like "onavo" do it?

Comment: Onavo installs a profile that activates the in-built IPSec VPN client in iOS. The Onavo app is not involved in the encryption directly

Comment: @Paulw11 tnx for the info, so by compression they mean default IPSec compression mechanism. I thought they do some custom compression client-side.

Comment: Onavo is owned by Facebook.  These are the last people I would be trusting with my privacy or security!